# How to run CREATE TABLE migrations ignoring foreign keys that do not exist yet on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table that has 3 foreign keys to other table using the references statement. But rails won't let me run the migration due that this is the first table I'm creating and those 3 foreign keys don't exist yet. Is there any way to make this easy?. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the foreign key from your table. You can do this completely by by remove the statement for the referenced table from you migration. Or you can change the your `t.references other_table` or `t.belongs_to other_table` to `t.integer other_table_id`. I would suggest just completely removing that column. Once you have the other tables you can add a reference in another migration.

#### add foreign key

```
add_foreign_key :table, :other_table
```

Comment: Thanks! which is the command to generate migration to add foreign key by console??

Comment: You can just create it how ever you want an replace it with the line above on the inside. `rails g migration AddUsersBooks`

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer xD